# Read wii remote battery level

Tags: python-3.x, batterylevel, wiimote

I currently have my wii remote connected to my Windows 10 x64 laptop, and have it recognized as a game controller (Julian Loer's gamepad drivers). Since it is Windows, and I am using python 3, cwiid is not availible.

I have been able to work around the issue, but the only problem I have is reading the battery level. When connected to my raspberry pi, I set the leds to show the battery percentage in binary, with 15 (1 + 2 + 4 + 8) being full.

Is there another way to read the battery level?

Comment: The question is in a review queue for quality. I think its a good question, but it could be closed. Maybe you should provide some of the code you use to read the battery level to help folks see its on-topic and get it out of the queue.

Comment: @jww I am asking for a possible module I could use. By code do you mean the code in my raspberry pi?